# Double math off no idea why, by .00000000x

Tags: java, precision

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. My math is off but by the smallest ammount.

I tried changing the DecimalFormat but I know its correct at where it's set now.  I looked at using long but I don't see why that would make a difference I'm not going past the size of double.

I made sure to check that I was working with all doubles. I'm not even sure exactly how to troubleshoot this.

Input data:

```
12
657 7
9079 13
9551 8
4633 7
8622 12
98 2
254 2
12040 11
14711 10
46254 8
8978 
62424 2
```

Expected result:

```
25.6343560524 95.2837866586 98.7716099678 71.3069977502 92.8547252433 25.7398989899 64.7460784314 109.726933795 121.288922541 258.904619449 566.427585376 15607.249984
```

My result:

```
25.6343560524 95.2837866586 98.7716099678 71.3069977502 92.8547252433 25.7398989899 64.7460784314 109.7269337948 121.2889225409 258.9046194492 566.4275853759 15607.2499839808
```

My code:

```
package com.secryption.CA18SquareRoot;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SquareRoot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Data: ");
        int numberOfTestCases = myScanner.nextInt();
        double r;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##########");


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTestCases; i++) {
            r = 1.0;
            int calculateSquareRootFor = myScanner.nextInt();
            int numberOfSteps = myScanner.nextInt();
            double d;

            if (numberOfSteps > 0) {
                for (int w = 0; w < numberOfSteps; w++) {
                    d = (double) calculateSquareRootFor / r;
                    r = (r + d) / 2.0;
                }
            }
            System.out.print((df.format(r) + " "));
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:  After talking to the site owner, double is correct.  I ended up trying a few different data sets and it finally saw it as correct.

Comment: Binary and Decimal are incompatible in a finite format, and all calculations on a computer are finite.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=double+wrong

Comment: @dimo414 So BigDecimal it is.

Comment: I think it has to be BigDecimal.  But I'm not exactly sure not to make r a BigDecimal since they're immutable.  I haven't worked with them much.  Workng on it now, I'll post back once I figure it out and retest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all values can be precisely represented by a `double`. Values that can't will be approximated, which is what you're experiencing here.

For example, the value *1/3* cannot be written as a finite decimal number: it would be infinitely long, *0.333333...*, but it could be written as a finite number in a ternary system, for example, where it would be *0.1*, or approximated in the decimal system as, e.g. *0.333334* (which is just a little off).

In analogy, there are many values that cannot be represented exactly as a binary number, which is what `double` uses internally. For example, it is impossible to store *0.1* as a binary number, the exact representation would be infinitely long and therefore a double will use an approximation.

Comment: I understand the issues with binary/decimal math.  Yet this problem has been solved previously by others.  ( I'm working through the codeabbey exercises.)  So then I can assume my code is correct, that's more what I'm worried about.